# TListbox , select items according to a pattern

Tags: delphi

The selection of Items get a painful work if your list box contains  many items and you need to select e.g. 400 items by manual clicking and selection. 
Is there a elegant way to select items from a List box using  a certain "**select items by pattern function**"  ???

Comment: this mean, get string, and analysze this string list ?

Comment: If you need to manually select 400 items in a listbox, you need to take a good look at your user-interface design.

Comment: @Andy_D Well, isn't that exactly what Franz is doing? By allowing the user to supply a pattern, he is obviating the need for said user to select items manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have code that can match a pattern. Let us say that it has this interface:

```
function MatchesPattern(const Value, Pattern: string): Boolean;
```

Then you can use the following function to select all items that match:

```
procedure SelectMatchingItems(ListBox: TListBox; const Pattern: string);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ListBox.Count-1 do
    ListBox.Selected[i] := MatchesPattern(ListBox.Items[i], Pattern);
end;
```

If you are prepared to use anonymous methods then you can use a predicate.

```
procedure SelectMatchingItems(ListBox: TListBox; 
  const Matches: TFunc<string, Boolean>);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ListBox.Count-1 do
    ListBox.Selected[i] := Matches(ListBox.Items[i]);
end;
```

This latter approach is the most flexible and is how you should tackle the problem if you have a Delphi with sufficient functionality.

Comment: `TFunc<string, Boolean>` == `SysUtils.TPredicate<string>` ;-)  However i'd allow the nil filter or at least would check for it